# Powershell Export to csv (keeping the original order of data)

Tags: powershell, csv

I have the following script that exports user's samaccountname based on their names. It is working/doing what it suppose to do.

```
$users = Get-Content C:\Users\metho\Desktop\users1.txt

$output = foreach ($user in $users){
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$user'" | Select-Object name, samaccountname
} 

$output | export-csv C:\Users\metho\Desktop\Users_Export_Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Original csv contains 527 users... the output csv has 480 users. Basically, the users that are not found are skipped in the output csv (but i want the output to list the missing users as well in a same order), which causes me an issue. I would like to have an output CSV that also lists the users that are not located on the system so i can do manual digging, at the moment i have to find the missing users myself by comparing the original csv with the exported csv, which is taking way too long.

is there a way that i can export csv with found user's username and also listing the users that arnt found on the system. I think it has to do something with export-csv switch. i am doing my best to locate the answer, maybe someone out there knows the answer?? any help would be highly appricated.

-metho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$users = Get-Content C:\Users\metho\Desktop\users1.txt

$output = @()
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$user'" | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName
    if ($adUser) {
        $output += $adUser
    }
    else {
        $output += [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name           = $user
            SamAccountName = 'Not found in AD'
        }
    }
} 

$output | Export-Csv C:\Users\metho\Desktop\Users_Export_Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

If a user is not found in AD, the output for that user will be

```
"Name","SamAccountName"
"Username as in the txt file","Not found in AD"
```

Comment: that did it. thanks. I would have never thought of this... is there anyway you can explain what is that you doing there... its just for my understanding.

Comment: @metho I'm a bit pressed for time now, but what happens is that if we DO get a user from AD, we add it to the output array. If not, we add an object with the same properties to the array containing the text that the $user could not be found. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Optmizing [Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55238509/6811411)s good answer in two points

- Assigning the foreach output directly to the var `$output` avoiding the `+=`
- integrating the assignment `$adUser = Get-ADUser ...` and the `if($adUser)` in one step.

---

```
$users = Get-Content C:\Users\metho\Desktop\users1.txt

$output = foreach ($user in $users) {
    if ($adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$user'" | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName){
       $adUser
    } else {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name           = $user
            SamAccountName = 'Not found in AD'
        }
    }
} 

$output | Export-Csv C:\Users\metho\Desktop\Users_Export_Test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```